# "while you grow" or "while growing"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one do you think is appropriately stated? Or which one sounds better?

> 1. Speed up customer service, while *you grow* your restaurant.
> 2. Speed up customer service, while *growing* your restaurant.

Comment: Neither is a complete grammatical sentence; they both appear to use the semi-grammatical language often used by English speakers (rather than English writers). Spoken English is often sloppier and more casual than written English.

Comment: @MarkRipley - I dunno, I think they're acceptable imperatives, no?  I agree that they are very informal-sounding, but I think they're grammatically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both examples sound more like fragments, rather than full sentences.

Regarding meaning, it is mostly the same.

Example 2 sounds slightly better and accents **"growing"**, while example 1 accents **"you"**. So depending on what you want to say, you can use either of them.